# What kind of string is this? What can I do in php to read it?

Tags: php, binary, base64, decode

This is a string (see below, after the dashed line) in a database.inf file for a free program I downloaded that lists some websites.

The file is plain text as you can see , but there is a string after it that *looks* base64 encoded (due to the end chars of ==). But b64_decoding it gives giberish.

I wanted to decode it so I could add to the list of sites it had (the program lists a bunch of sites and data about them which I can read in the GUI) and to do that I need to decode this, add to it, and re-encode it.

I think the program uses .net since I think the .net library was required on install, but I know nothing of the original source language.

I am using php to figure out if there is a simple way to read this. I have tried using unpack, binhex, base_convert, etc as I suspect the file is binary at some level, but I am lost.

Nothing illegal, just wanting to know what it is and if I can add a few things to it to make it more useful for me. 
here is the file - any ideas how to decode and recode this for playing with?

---

Site List
file size: 62139
db version: 13
generated: 2010-04-27 11:53:40

eJztPWmT27iVnze/gjVVk56pXXXz1BW3XW2PPXaNr/iIa69SUSIkMaZIhaQstys/fgHwEIiDBEjQk6Q2lUraeuAD8PDwbgAPtkl6eBoZsX8At1enDKRXRvGfL350gj/9uEmBn4MVAqFGP14Z+f0R3FoP//CA+Rb9ddXj26OfZYJ+EeicpEHrt/5V/2/XA75FDTjzlf7WvlL/NgWXnlW/BQc/jPjzxaAfMUzU7+Xr7m+pj7cVZ/C63pa8Iewa/e+299fbMM3yuv8+fa8wCs5Cy/W9EmwLztfU51Eb2SKZoUe9v458gmq9+l4hFDyiS/W9Ei0Z52tO5/W8+VQ3aGwipvcjIRGUMPmnfN8XE40qCFKABSaFpgQg2ggGARtwB9D55SbM77lfIkCxGIIvsxw2460jBrRxwbfwyJdVEFB2eSERTaTstP4r2OQsG+RhHoEfL7+XOGy6d9yObKaKwE/zJo4eCFYNDD0QhJsIXHD0RHAZRV8EzF6WRQCXkU/ECnDBIUSwB37A8oEsgg3kuF2S3rOCtASwCNq1H4ECCYVCuTT4mRlDUwH2QNDUgT1HcFGDfUewIobQjaBVGdIYkMqoV0I8h2gIgqZK7DmCi1bsOYKVcB25CFp1I38djAY6wXqeokg8Enk8qEWSXg0eT4GHGFFPPMk5BmkHn8rgaVoOA+ZVStCaTgPoo2U8eBzD6bNdHUHci38Ycwi14Xk2F0C7aCpZh3Vv1BAQQ1BFUDDdAATk9PsjuBiW/WjQGIUqglPamACBAJpBH9+9JIwFsbkE27GaXhoBXkZiHKoIzmCdhTnH9VBEsKrHoIoAfd0gZB8i8pexAnQpGMhBySndsIKmAnDsJc6GXocJX1RBQJfJViwkgaEfAmIMqgjI0fcbwTo55cINLYOg0BsXPL1GQGrnnkQMQA65hvRWxQgoDAHINlxbBQHS8JiHSUz6nswQiHZXvRCUVGzi4SNpV98NDCoIstPh4BPeR8scWkdA4FFEkOVJo38JBBSGz+AehSWzKwZDBekwe8s5EHj6IVhdMHQioN3AJM5BnHPWocQtsSFXTSTqCPAc1klAhWLUEAyaAmpGzKIfghx87UuDQqYMQFBFNGoMiggu1JcmImP5VpGD8BKW4AcV2udQtV2FZCqAiwCOIQeHYwSBxotfbq/uChTGL362Xyd+GhhRsgtjOzutD2EOO7g+7o9XD//wbw+yI9iEfrRCmB5KffbgpvENxLGN/F328O/P/axo//e7U54U3/z9wU0Bhc0wDNk+D2+4aC/wS+MMpA+DZHM6QIa83oH8aQTQn9nj+9eQVj9BYtd5qZ//2/zfa0ymGhX6usaFsicduOrMC4sLf13j2oZxmO0f3tQzwCKYnEbZAlEYt0HzsvkfkA1g+xTswiyH/gKmVBbu4tOxaNiAXDAXQrpjanW08jI149b4oQzU/fCn/4H/6cRQKRkKB6knJDHhbUahqTaYJApob9IYahNUEgVUDjSKWl/88Kd6ZUoCXygeJDEoludwX466sZQ1nPokSpLPcKtb9UZ7f9psoEeGgi33xtsELm7QRFJ/ATGVDnXRcfmPolsSQjQkMTx8C2IDTb3Z510QoC65X5C8KMVjDSeTomsjlSizPGU+Uhc6ztYmEdWpVbmh6cS2paQXiahIHMlgiVqwRNJYSmpbAkRVGkkGVZHd4eNBCR4ZHDgrxUeB81IyOIr8FB9JkaJCO51mdCTpUSx2s/fjHXhom+Z8YjoT2zKsxdKyl5YHBT3R4A8PbioF/JBWxjdhHICvaKc+Ovo7cIsVBKt8uc10KFs+Xo62rTb+R6g3jZdkM0IkSCpm1GBV8qQ1TC8Tm43GxNfK9YRZZUz+u54VnKrx5pQ3W5NzbqhwipwNjc4o88s/rRrhc5AC4z45GRs/NooGRgzORmUVkEgsrjTmLWsFHGImNPOBPS0FKqJNK3l++FcebRaHxyPIh9kgNTK+QXOxRGRsAGohDlBCwv+XNwb+E9os1eIbe7iv1wBUjNFqEHB+t5vYwqwDj82RdLOJucCSbrq05kvPVJB0aGdf413EdzCoBkLpdhdFydl4/uHVS0LQ8aUbjbGPF1FERAc7EBLuA7Gzy6FDnXpN2JCPHjW2PyN9ur/hOBH4o+Kn1EdbBH8FZc4BHNYgvX0Nzv/+Cv85RHoMkhp15EZsj3du6ktUlyd0UERSWjIUGMpIyCe4w5Pzdf0Zcl6uwzgGKeJQUmKgf0t0IuVHcUSPijlOKuAhpuUlJT3MuMTjoTdaH1ten+2t046vckOsJsF5me/FvRQSWQa+BO0xB19JWcRYT1gLw7KgObw05wp6ohhndiMyhRtwCRuYrxooLH00w8dLdGmgFfu224ptCPpq8NU63ARJp5ynvxkizT8MkebvdQSKnoXsACrDbRuKzDMVGfmRjR2S27+ua+8e61ttgqTC9CSJoZl8GI7wGTK2Xw9XBC/9VjSyeuCpBhXwOEx2qX/cs4b7RVRKSjBvYi8M21ma9tK25SXYVRs2c2nPl46CPCzDgR9SP4CG2iY5CEPzlya9pSL+86afOMQHSLTYydIh9uZwOzx56PxAD+oLgF4PEeSETXcgMKCHIOPiW1WU/qbdEuc04ojkWnxr8Mt1uOVaQvhknq93EL9RwTDYYJfwHzQY1MMVhS4L+G64YkBNH8uhURGmlr10vKXlKpiD5+OkLWhAgnWEDJr4+shB2EyDGDzLRQpsPGI/OEA5eEyyfAIdd4nMITnLR/4Gbe2WIGH970omvit/MJ4lqfFhH2bGe+jfEB+ywlNiE6HxDwsvHjZwowRhDt0cc5iXrsPBLhyYwVJByTlW3IzmdOk6CpuxULjGT2s/MPb5IfqZsyOZNv+61ohena9f4Uhzg2UhT92ZLW1LnhtevH/6y+vrJN2xTFCDdIjkgp6TykjhMwSRrwlj44/G+yJ3clfnTYYkq/TUkGC9KS3W6VkX/nsp6itgPOGVGAiqRZoI+WUjjAR/gpnKuIuNu80mOcU5j7bD5H5lXw6zO1uqRiQjr63WJoFjoG4gTkMNc7oPYRBEYAXdlRxuMArZ9wveQn/z6Mc07SXI3Vq9IV9OMLwQ4JgmX8J401UJ0IkG2i/MOqiVNRz3SUwPQ6KQwf/KlFN8h6i0DneFI117mkn6wvUbNVRKSnaG0qa2Sji8zfnR5flUYptE2Fdf+hqrLv0VZYAV9O7Umit5rVj9a2gVpZ8OrYxYZVC/5/i0wMAITL6KwvgzOgvUP+OUrvApT95oWK0qwPb4/kXw01WIwtXICUueQtfMuvp5UOp0oPLlcmdPiVNwp6geTkHgFIhsHYh0yGR/aKIRSo0NLiUYppb9lZSKUgrmm0vbWbrTVvkbhKkB0d9enc/na0j5z0kcQoZNY5DX8XckH/jgBzel7EBc9PCVn34GeRjvDD8OjAxEEfo7ieH/AeMc5nvDN7KDH0VGkhr75ACM9SmDsAxa1RgBRLRLkl0EHk6ga1b+CX/0I/DVx78Vf1Fh6n2eH5c3N/wh3hQG/Ko04K+Rl94azx6EzVYTpNXlHT3laHFiqVVicUQIyy7uxLQxu7hLh/WJIYswnOIf/G9o5RgeIQFN7rgrIcxau+xSW3PPnBGrrexHE4tIjuimqPMpolXXm+1hQJkUa9KPVy3VyPmozq0jVbRPwfb2Bzib2pCA3z7CLFjWdK7uk1NaQTO51JFokFQ/sjtRFgdr9IiQ1LYQxvD7pqSInI1Ffq9S80WWaykIA2VnXlMllQZfXOOxCP1VCxIGjqQu7yGci0Vfh99Y8dwAUQK6rJV9HH5jZPSUldGeNTOtVhlNSGaRaGgMh3Jo2tPOvbCoq2fUUhzEIoq4ZYodMTZhKEqlCLzExbWAiYsopBENEl8ljuFByQpRq0U+kkWTAT+FLaqAMbT3GhuHBTc3z3sMv0SJqf3jcWwcZ+bNZ90mLdszFd1W0aPKyBR3DK8uqvdJB26FlBJ3D6rdu2tVqTLFf+Eu9vNTyqfIqNxcWSXNQipKC+REDRVPERQ1VlK87E3nU132Oj24MjX6KABZfnvJPP7DJkqFxrrSxIYVeMkd4WodnFSKtxVDnf6lZ6jrYBZzrFL1aFaADoKE6xOK36zIm9V0H9ZqdKTjiAcPr86SturiiGFJxuoEXHk5T3e6UX3REOrVMfLZ6pN2Kfv/FW/aPBRvYs9wScV8abGH5HjqqQyKTzZJmvoRo59YcK2gdFzTgfVZGac3nuA+GCXnsErOtheeaxNaToeiBpUtVoRJGVJw4PppUZmtxhvciUyEbu5NvXkHLSxMCw+Ro5MWMUhqC5QgQfNn/TN/DZK76sSyRFjSsuYzT+OsCb2Zhpu9yFCrYKOtvPEO9iBDAddzGk6/RgJ8gYLGF1GgBo5Ggr+gHmTEgOWac1RHqJUGh/tS5q1PYcQz2XkN9NPi1b1RycXHRT9SFHHMhauTK2r/FP4CNijJsUuioEETcRP9VPml6uJX2IVRY6p+ldk39tS1zREo5KbgmIZxzqUNCRxRabjGu6IfhhAmJ2o4s217JBG69UOhr1vBxhOhz2APDAVsDis4c9ObjkOBLAY5SlqKqEDCR+SI10UvUrLDMq2FTkMCzTZOcnD0g+vySG1FhMvPIxgSBW6ZKU89+B9X85RPx9M6gq4+nNw2acy6AdE/8Y/G2wI/USLbLQ8905nqXvUqDRAleS4OehHg8WTB46ITGW6YzSxzoZkS2xSAKqA7CcAxYWs5+E30U+QZ7OeiMlE/MkRxp/OF9i2Shrt9dT8RQw8aqJ8S71APFSmkbG3L9izdiuLo536cQ1syO0VFRUulGr748JcGTTra6ifRW9whMkFRj/DPzHiBi29wgRXHS+eEomeOO7VnI6lXHG0SKtcaOp5qvUNdyFgZlu0ubO2CxY8i6BsgsxLE4JQijcJSg99mBJpE0VOioxdYvUlQZr5wF7oZBHyrHRJGAVMw/YR4+l+17m3xSni6Z+o4C61uCcrAX2++3dSapRrOxTkRNhlPHSu5apY7s2Y6iUKIiA2I2GgnBRuPDE9gDzI+GnRVLVMnBa7a+xN3ZZmoK9vDZ6ndpSMXXa62G9bpcXIWCmyywXgyGyv+18mZIT2nxtW25wvt7lCtn04b1vChgeOx33vUhYwKt73ZwtYdYSvn+dlPD8IoYw0cjQi/oR6kAkbuwprqjpOgaxn/dgIZMlKuT58pY68BG8O4KzuQmf5s6lnaI+1lOGxSRlJZH4CFj+AGFJ1UcVYZYixmnjOSResHX+AgTqlQLjQajCcb7qpuZMwW6BU5nnYNbU2SYx4ewm/FxZCku9MkTEvDEQhkTd4QvUlEnzuPTggLOFom1nr9Pldnu4YJdba5NNkLolv48VAdIamP2lP82GgwHj/WR1nkMkLWCOGKKvcHcpSXF6YGL+ARs4NFJ1J7E7rf2oMWdRKQVyxAA8cjw19C2UoBbzGf6SZCqZW2JxCBgKECAx2tYuIZ7kKKDObMm+q244LT4RCCbHcKA5Cz0QcWrJ8QH/bwu6If41fUkQwxFtO5N9ettML4S5iFaygW16xRSwP1E+JF1cOrx3cyNHBm5szVLSfzvZ9nh/s43OxZK4YGjsEMsAfj1b3xGvUhRQUbunj6qVBVCp2TNGLlAwc+zsaovv+EupGSElNvrt3TgdMtJeImSWNONojXYByCEIVmsWw9heNYuhkEneGr8htMiJIG6qcEvo2/23jl88fMHKligCkr4cBGsyd+ffPyF5mAtePazlglEwdo2SXHJAo5J3l5LUa0uOt+pIooZtPFQmuMskqKnsG6FAwsSTjwETKm754+NT6BdSU4pOgxm831kwO/5wGCyy1arIXBNhjDysC9iOsLeEkec6rf9IS+FhRcqJA6Cr9A37Ccdp3A4ASUuj8YI8JU9Wq8xN1KyF2e2IF62TV10/Ds7w9ihmKg+qnz6e75q4kSK808z/S66r77yl8/Pol92gt0zEgH6kMmLWTPp+58rMx6GGcoTSJMTxDwEQvXXhS9tGwUHl2mtjt3RmKQjTj0sxk57POEE/HhZSqcETRxHd3yo4M49FUC+RSQfEaOCnRBlHJli97CstpnPZ2YHn4TxFracolLZF9wdASdqhE3G06JZr2WyjaYtO8AdWocQbqF3QuVBQc+fP5vC6RiY4PHDPbcnC/aC+DVpr+FIyZWuTF1DkzDssO2Brn2UpUSpgudM93LTs6NTgJQMD3srjBjG/rl3rRdB6rN+LN/hhPa+2WRLkpskIvNBw+f928l3qp4l5fp4B6AWkxnHcEa9RWvHG6opUAsdMdrqJLCk7CAfsWYZQoTPHPecYpDffKHe7E5TMF0TfzVvUy9GO/Qn23PdS7+8Logc7F00Du0UqT+GzR0w/yeECIsyQVtdJH+zwX6hqiV8kJcqGQcnSqG2Fq1ESEMAjVbfIdCPZYm3GIpx5yJhfGFSWboIkSLvYiWR5Mo8FEEND0USXD6HhgWrJ8aL3+5I/ooeKVinH6uvOWZC7GeJgllzXg3RnLzkX6aRGHsC7cSr8EIWcmyF6XjJ9bUk6LHdOnA/y7kNtN60xkQErQZYUM9ftLvoKJltVXPk5RBkkaOU8opx+DrSShhauB4wuU16kLGk7Es1xbXYJI0gBvGk9M9+LwNMt3F2p7fRJfmwVIEm/nCjcIlxXwxd3UavGQAIzkcw6guNuLGOJpNRqyNvnQk5/qYltgSarCIs/TkBMgO1dhUS4/Ef3JgmUTUSBeb/IrwX8xD2IPxCnYhQ5Pp3LQX7fHi/iZKNQGhhUI2GNFAqb6VqmOeOmJyXHjEW3rO0mZfJuKGz4tLoi8SgrZPeA108canArdSbMRFx5BGchiz2M/Fl2ZcoKOxw3vchSEZM+Pdm7bwxDZ9g0MgbeSkyD5Zr+87DRFhK1288hx10C/hb9mLxdTSHVYqJzspbkAE8Y53246okeaQw+Q9gf93ia0GAByFhggNHOFGDdiDkvvrebOZ3E5xob6Vk6U130+S7UVeMrUx4mYj3jRivNkq2WmOYzVvYGwhkLc0lZIwAeaGA+/EBLeFrs1SvryFK4deg7MwMv099osfJPgCvWr9W1y8tpYjaKKyu74RvelUcl85ztLp3lenz9fr1IcuzBpOoUEbBqKLTR4jrOjGhZ1avmpmubO5tSCPSHPuxmSGfUOvSvN2TJbZqucnoQqXOL9YC5jsGAYg3VCnF/lgQT4A3U143bnLMKInyScleWPPLdsy20vc1XdZvgenzxIJ0JZ2Q0iBqjU//tYv++k4ZmuMrR9BCmue5x83IIJJFxeaZjdtiaBPFR6pU3nzmWe77RuGGRxxhqjaOYUYl9s5tolOEXEekW/XWAnvjCML5l98zL+nhHfZhNes6Zd765W9NJcYEfssWXXK6nd5wrP9XZL2y4TJWcXgXCVuO98pa8fU/oiZyrWuJZks4VMWRq8nKQQof4dXAs9aHgjUgaX7kS2ll60slNCRiLxW70t9jpMz5KIdyKAxSR2Cb2nTlA6Py4a/VQ3f44ZydQPedDZvF5wt42hKzqGPTpVojIFP+BVIylro/pfko3umfchPrzks71Nvn0lcle9NzJlhLZauJVtqhp4P3KWodoI9JULBmvzwEgJ/LYBy94pMZ2YHD3D6pF955L3P0EoGp3ubVLgBfv01TU4x97JNGt4kB6qdM57iFv1MKNtcLOwOc1wwEuFl9TzKWCaijDNbmtLmODSjwm+UFcaC+MbE86KBlH01c8xGgYWSPcEO6FIR1PqM+IfE8IPA8GOj2tX3yck4nLIc9Uq8JqD+QCpu9l2fppcgxiP8rvhtYZJImSIcbMVra1mBb5PfHtNkGyKztvOV8WdhFBnQhTG2IYiCzFgD9EpGnhhVS8M34NgMRKP/QE8lwj8MqAv4T4+rGDz0avS0KzTdY6/nGnuogLZymNTeL8ZCwptDZ03eZ4c0PO8TvsN+gTXFxEe4uJ/27M1lPB9zbi08zjMrtXiwZeQDOZSbR2Fwe2f9k7yCKN7m7JwclX3Nfm7L7uMwRsIyNQKQQ2rUm3kPYmMThZvPxnv0SAu6p+6ev3+5zGfhwjZXJnO82QP/CB3ufZKh+you0WoMKH9NwZcQnOGCfAk3IMNPwAdIeJGcOhRRk62foI/wMbbnxZeqtoDpTht3vHAWf+iI6+W/3EFHvYZVx/snuDgDA7MsTGJJSwOvI8pIdIcvAHqa8pJfICufWVCT1k8x/BIA9nN/7cfs9cs8kYKumeqwudjui5+ouI4KSTx76XbfC4NyLMckiVA86QtcwKbfxoU2CfOphBjobsi3sK2Ur2YvPIvz+KycEcYdVfnQ0z/wm1WcZefPROVVKD6G+lWoYcEbuTd55PW9ZVjmEp1R6t6qB7gF/CrBgxK5IcWaogbUc9m4Ve0r3RXtpG4GXszdRUccVjSGm80unKwhNxbfXB/ZUIKYPlAloepACa86gUvHPj9a/yqIWJ+Pk64gPYFCppoRDn/Bf2Sx4XTXWNEQsHtwc4T6QylW2cAhGaWsDIF3lemPCq7yfQgNCUgIeYsBBcWK67bkEgto2ML8Pw1ssi2CKpUAefa0+W6SYA3obrtixmI29dylK0cHaz6fC+lAA5t0QFAxHXinR1zT7q1XeOMpUwVFOLCPasm/5vrSBRBZ/4wBMzXqVVJuyFO0ERlk9WYs0PR/fjD/WgVhBwQ8v+aDIq9oDDix1x1T70Cj5b1AiKd8t7DjOcOBb/DBflqyIj3zNfwN0DMswt8APUMbENkmidXwyXBO63PpJVRyrvskBtSTjlIfbv2vVz0+Qwqxz3eohNyP7zlrLPW5jlcbEZulNBLZwR/Y9IqiXWstzfnSlCuKq+RmmEV+LKy2JsACS67weIyf1n5gIKn7c+fVCxij1LGvKXTQzPZLsvtUeE0Ofp6GX5mS6gZk6HSDySuMS+qiuOl0Pm2/B6zH8eow9uMNmFTpxknksxekixo1LaBnRSujSowad3FgvPTPxrsydymXFlvYjt0W1ey0i0Sj/ad0u1snVHrfjx5J20JCVC1uuHIqWUcmWefjxZIPLEtiwy8h63gHuXgGufsRZDG6D/6uwBhu07p4pUzBfwrjIDlf1x+uk+D+OoxjkCLUSqNmu7GVumlO6V/q8WVfT9ZqLYdG6QFmdNBsaUkeVi1PXYYb4YHMAqRHvUNkMlX+C2vutFSx91Ts8b3Qw6dgVAI/vlc6VOzC0VtOd5yD6vQGWt3tfq6CfyoWVTKlXoWxSYtNpeqbwt5Ex+3V7M3yeWvBre8EmFtkofJytTdz3Mapq9LeuItQ5g7JLNLgaK9wJMZF1+nwIlbKirVd7SgsibN0F7LnUMEXkN4HvnjX8BpQGSmqhdx9g1OnsS4C0vN6V01BFbLSlKNHtkmSY/U0SpMSTVCTBu8R7M+yD55YrjdrXvAhmH6zy5tqAyhTwF3ai6Ut9zgDCj5P3JCdPwmgiuPevPlt4r74IBcgXkwtTtmT0o4kh0JHDwfuRa7Jtg3TLP/RKP6BaChjhHAxyZofG5+R7fAnsEvSe5kYRF/7nAk+qZnkjKWjZjpvWkKcCvIPcru3tLtLefAVQGeQsamr+tcmn/8Z/Sz18LU7h//t3t91P9+jOgHSxYHaWu4Ki3wPinOxRSEdTSAW3KQUOl1TnHs18I2+UifoZ47tSKSO2L6pkmmV/JGLLn2xJF/USsEhBOnlEBJtwPAaNOnytmiheHDc9UyZvCave/pATrvx2UKluaxF4Uw9oTFBwZq0gUCVU2kLy5pyMmyEHpEPKlHjujkkwQn9jeo90Uhu0bnU1d1mk5zQK16/71Ed1HzVP/vWOdfiKO6qPoErGXxSouEfkyMqycVTHxKTyvBzo6qGs0pEAl08qz8XpS8RhblBR8BDxFY9Ax8NdLbmCAiSSTN8SlnpPohjmgjvpKpgXJfzLQTKnbA2p5wjgn28zWo8OGKQnOOBdi2bkqIO3LTustO6Mj5XvVJrKG6ozb2doVsNJC9IIa929ONA9BikuBmVBFG9yXEOdZQpcYhWPIBKga+qEq5BbLD1/Q1vCfu7ORgjV/4o+TsYzaDUQoFhUEwMo1hHp5T1Y+jziyrcOlc80ZztEyg9henYGsqPjj1HYKnaV3QxokQQgukXiaQoxAXX1352fARlw61m0SRf2kI4qPRZ3MvCK62XN1tacqGSKs+2D3f7CL9YQHsE3Bb8k6bG86qNzOKhBzssicXjDgDfkDBpOgRDAtFf83LrGkbPzYtQ7IEfQJYaXKG0Gn5MFSJZ36NgbwdjyiDCQrVL5sqNCbOkEJOkwEaICnnNrJaSxEZ4tJZA1c3RAkKyHPRgxYZoU0ooV+asypv2VqLKHgUBM8e3RIoiDv8H/FOXyg==

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us what program generated this.

Comment: why would this help? the program is a compiled windows exe that reads this file. Is there a tool to decompile the exe and see source?

Comment: i think it's base64 with swaped charmap, it may be possible to read this custom charmap out from exe with some ResourceEditor

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood they created this string in such a way that you couldn't change it.

This isn't that they haven't thought about whether or not they want the data to be changed, they have specifically sought to obfuscate it to make it harder to change, which suggests they don't want you to do it.

Given that you are using some else's code, you should carefully check what license covers your use of the code and whether it permits you to make the modification. Once you've done that, you should approach the originator of the code to ask them how to make the change, if you feel you are entitled to.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a script that contains this string. Check if you have eval() function calling this string to be base64_decode (ed). Change the eval to print. Then, execute it, redirecting the output to a file for later reading.

```
kevin@server:~# php suspicious_script.php > out.php
```

You should be able to see what's going on.